# Is it a correct kanji 「渡せ」?

Tags: kanji

Sorry for the weird question, as I don't know the proper title for my question.
So, my problem is, how I read the kanji after the word 「アイテムを。。。」.

Here's the image of the text I read.

[image]

It was really hard to read the kanji on the back. I've been using KanjiTomo to help me decipher the kanji, but it was still hard to catch the meaning of the kanji. All of the result given completely out of context on regards with first few words at front.

[image]

BTW, I'm a complete newbie on Japanese so please don't be to hard on me. :) 
Thank you.

Comment: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/je/81887/meaning/m0u/ (definition #3/4) / http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/渡す (definition #2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's 渡せ, which is the imperative form of 渡す (わたす, "to pass, to hand, to give"). The sentence says "Pass the item (to me, to someone, to the statue in front of you, etc.)." See the second line of your search results, and you'll find a more relevant definition.

渡る is an intransitive version of 渡す.